# Stop Tensorflow trying to load cuda temporarily

Tags: tensorflow

I have this code to disable GPU usage:

```
import numpy as np

import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"

import tensorflow as tf
w = tf.Variable(
    [
        [1.],
        [2.]
    ])
```

I get this output still, not sure why :

```
E:\MyTFProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/MyTFProject/tfvariable.py
2021-11-03 14:09:16.971644: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-11-03 14:09:16.971644: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-11-03 14:09:19.563793: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:271] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2021-11-03 14:09:19.566793: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: newtonpc
2021-11-03 14:09:19.567793: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: mypc
2021-11-03 14:09:19.567793: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

TF Version: '2.6.1'
Not able to stop it from loading Cuda DLLs. I dont want to setup cuda just right now. Maybe later.

I am using the latest PyCharm and installed tensorflow as given in the site with pip.

Comment: There is no issue here, there is no problem if the CUDA libraries are not found, it will just not support GPU in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall tensorflow with CPU-only version. The links are available here depending on your OS and your python version:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=fr#windows_1

Comment: There is no CPU-only TensorFlow for TF 2.6

Comment: I didn't try to install it but you have a link in the tf website to install tensorflow2.6 with cpu. For Linux and python3.9: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.6.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl